# SpotBugs - Method ignores results of InputStream.read()

Tags: java, spotbugs

I am having some problems debugging a code, I managed to debug all bugs but one:
`Method ignores results of InputStream.read()`, the debugger (SpotBugs) says the problem is on `reader.read(buffer, 0, n)` and advises me to check the return value otherwise the caller will not be able to correctly handle the case where fewer bytes were read than the caller requested.

```
    char[] buffer = new char[n];

    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        reader.read(buffer,0,n);
        reader.close(); 
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<buffer.length;i++) {
        int swap = i % 2;
        if (Integer.toString(swap).equals(Integer.toString(1))) { 
            buffer[i] = ' ';
        }           
    }
    System.out.print(buffer);
```

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

`read()` when used with a buffer returns the actual number of the bytes read (or -1 for end of stream). It's possible that the buffer isn't filled completely with a single read (although small buffers are, since data is transferred in blocks), so you need to make sure (i.e. use a `while` loop) you've read the amount of bytes you intended to.

Answer (score 0):

R. Castro gave you good explanation, but what's missing (in obvious words) is you are not checking how many bytes are being read from file. The number can be different than size of your buffer. That's what spotbug is trying to tell you. Your file can be longer or shorter than buffer size. You are not handling the case where file is longer than buffer size. And loop you have needs to be changed to whatever number of bytes are read than buffer.length